# ActiveRecord query using includes and restricting date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to show the @ratings of Reservations as long as its "end" field is less than Time.now.

This works (but without the time restriction):

```
@ratings = Rating.where(user_id: current_user.id).includes(:reservation).includes(:room)
```

I'm trying to restrict the query with "reservations.end < Time.now", like this:

```
@ratings = Rating.where(user_id: current_user.id, reservations.end < Time.now).includes(:reservation).includes(:room)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ratings = Rating.includes(:reservation, :room).where(user_id: current_user.id).where("reservations.end < ?", Time.now)
```